# Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region - for a few minutes after removing the reservation

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using flexible reservations for bigquery and turn them on/off for larger jobs. However after turning them off and (somewhere else) a query is started, it will fail with the "Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region" error. This happens for about 20 seconds, and then everything works fine.

What I do for turning flex reservations on is:

- create a commitment
- create a reservation
- create an assignment
  wait 60 seconds
  (this works fine)

What I do for turning flex reservations off is:

- remove the assignment
- remove the reservation
- remove the commitment
  Now we are entering a short "twilight" zone where the error can happen. After some time, everything starts working normally

Is this normal behaviour? Is there anything in the removement procedure that can be done to avoid this?

Comment: Are there any jobs that are running, when you deleted the reservation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to prevent that issue.

1. Delete the assignment
2. Wait for 2-3 minutes
3. Remove Reservation
4. Remove Commitment

I tested this and it worked for me.